# Can I view a google doc if I have its URL without access to google drive?

Tags: google-docs

my internet connection doesnot allow me to reach google drive. Can I still view a google doc if I have its URL ? Or can I save it as a doc or pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Viewing directly with the URL is working for me.  You'll have to log in, of course.

Once you're viewing the file, you can select "Download As" from the File menu to save to one of several formats, PDF included.